# How to code fold a SQL select sub query in MSSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms, code-folding

I have a select query that is big in terms of number of lines . It is made big by a large sub query it needs. I do not want to see the sub query so often now. I want to scroll over it when further developing my main query. I have Intellisense enabled. I want to be able to collapse my sub-query with a +/- next to it.

The subquery is:

```
inner join (select Dave.ID, .........) as Dave
on Dave.ID = Mike.ID
```

Is there anything I can write before and after the above sub-query (Dave) that will fold it so I do not have to see the sub-query (Dave) all the time?

Comment: I am assuming you have the Tools>Options>Text Editor> intellisense>Outline statements option checked!

Comment: If a query is so long that it requires folding, it's *too* long and too complex. Fix it instead. Break it apart into separate views or CTES, *eliminate* subqueries etc. It will also be *slow* because one clause will end up preventing another from using indexes, or force the server to spill data into tempdb.

Comment: What does the query do? Reporting queries for example are infinitely faster and easier to write if you move the data into a reporting schema first. Adding a Calendar table can eliminate a *lot* of date, month, year and name calculations *and* speed up the query. Windowing functions can eliminate subqueries that calculate running totals, averages etc

Comment: BEGIN and END enables folding in SSMS.

Comment: @EzLo Can we use BEGIN END inside sub query?

Comment: I misread, the OP is doomed.

Comment: Is there a simple solution to collapse part of a query? I work in Finance and not a db admin. The query/sub query is not that enormous. It still runs in zero seconds. Yes, outline statements ticked.

Comment: I've re written the code as a CTE. How do I expand and collapse that?

Comment: @Dasal Kalubowila I don't think SSMS allows partial collapsing of a query, all you can do is reduce scrolling by moving the sub-query out of the way with a CTE..

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to folding is to use a CTE structure to reposition the subquery.

```
;WITH Dave AS (
    SELECT Dave.ID,.....
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Mike    
        INNER JOIN Dave
        ON Dave.ID = Mike.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Write a CTE or Temp table.
2. Index the table if its a temp table.
3. Use it in the main query where ever needed